# Drupal form redirect preventing multiple submit handlers from executing

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I have a custom module that has a form which contains a form redirect in the submit handler.

I'm using a hook_form_alter, and appending another custom submit handler, for a total of two submit handlers. The redirect is preventing my second handler from executing. When I remove the redirect, the function works perfectly. Any ideas on how to prevent a redirect from messing up the custom submit handler?

- I can't change the order of the form alter, meaning I can't have the redirect submit hook be second.
- I can't put the redirect in the second handler, because it's not concerned with my form alter.

Some code:

```
/*
Original form handler
*/  
function example_form_handler($form, &$form_state) {
  //some logic to insert into a db and then...
  $form_state['redirect'] = '';
  drupal_redirect_form($form_state);
}

/* Form alter in another file*/
function sm_integration_form_alter(&$form , &$form_state, $form_id) {
   //this is altering the above form.
   if ($form_id == "my_data_form" ){
    //alert the form weight to be populated at last
    $form['submit']['#weight'] = 5;
    $form['#submit'][] =  'sm_integration_enable_submit';
  }

}

/* This code is not being executed with the redirect */
function sm_integration_enable_submit(&$form, &$form_state) {
 watchdog('sm_integration', 'This code does not execute with the redirect in the original module enabled');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are trying redirect to the homepage

Specify the homepage(baseurl) $url on the redirect

```
$form_state['redirect'] = $GLOBALS['base_url'];
```

Comment: You're right, having the blank string was causing the problem. Good to know.